# Creating an area chart: path with NaN

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am starting with D3 and trying to recreate example from the [url](https://observablehq.com/@d3/area-chart#data)

I am getting this error

```
Error: <path> attribute d: Expected number, "MNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNL…"
```

Attribute d is referred to each and every data. But why is it coming as MNaN?

I would be thankful, if the solution provider explain how the debug is done.

```
data = [
    {
      "date": "2007-04-23",
      "close": 93.24
    },
    {
      "date": "2007-04-24",
      "close": 95.35
    }];
    //Update 1
    data = data.map((item) => ({date:item.date, value:item.close}))
            data.y = "$ Close";
    //Update 1     

   height = 500;
width = 500;
margin = ({ top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 30 });
x = d3.scaleTime()
    .domain(d3.extent(data, d => d.date))
    .range([margin.left, width - margin.right])
y = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([0, d3.max(data, d => d.value)]).nice()
    .range([height - margin.bottom, margin.top])
xAxis = g => g
    .attr("transform", `translate(0,${height - margin.bottom})`)
    .call(d3.axisBottom(x).ticks(width / 80).tickSizeOuter(0));
yAxis = g => g
    .attr("transform", `translate(${margin.left},0)`)
    .call(d3.axisLeft(y))
    .call(g => g.select(".domain").remove())
    .call(g => g.select(".tick:last-of-type text").clone()
        .attr("x", 3)
        .attr("text-anchor", "start")
        .attr("font-weight", "bold")
        .text(data.y))
area = d3.area()
    .x(d => x(d.date))
    .y0(y(0))
    .y1(d => y(d.value))
const svg = d3.select('svg')
    .attr('width', width)
    .attr('height', height)

svg.append("path")
    .datum(data)
    .attr("fill", "steelblue")
    .attr("d", area);

svg.append("g")
    .call(xAxis);

svg.append("g")
    .call(yAxis);
```

Here is the [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/alaksandarjesus/zdbt65mk/3/)

Update 1

I need have the data in date and value and y..... but i had date and close..... updated the code in jsfiddle too.
Now i am getting the x and y axis but the error message remains the same.

[Update 1 Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/alaksandarjesus/zdbt65mk/4/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Understanding the error in the path's d attribute

When you get a `NaN` in a path creates by a line (or an area for that matter), you have to check *where* is the `NaN`. For instance:

```
MNaN,NaNL...
  ↑   ↑
  x   y
```

This shows that the problem is in both `x` and `y` methods. On the other hand, when you get:

```
MNaN,42L...
  ↑   ↑
  x   y
```

The problem is in the `x` method, while...

```
M42,NaNL...
  ↑   ↑
  x   y
```

... shows that the problem is in the `y` method. According to your updated JSFiddle, the problem comes from the `x` method.

#### Your problem

The problem is that you're passing things like this to the time scale:

```
"2007-04-24"
```

This is not a date, this is just a string. You have to parse the dates. For instance, given your string format:

```
data.forEach(function(d){
    d.date = d3.timeParse("%Y-%m-%d")(d.date);
});
```

Here is the code with that change:

```js
data = [{
    "date": "2007-04-23",
    "close": 93.24
  },
  {
    "date": "2007-04-24",
    "close": 95.35
  }
];

data.forEach(function(d) {
  d.date = d3.timeParse("%Y-%m-%d")(d.date);
  d.value = d.close;
})

height = 500;
width = 500;
margin = ({
  top: 20,
  right: 20,
  bottom: 30,
  left: 30
});
x = d3.scaleTime()
  .domain(d3.extent(data, d => d.date))
  .range([margin.left, width - margin.right])
y = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([0, d3.max(data, d => d.value)]).nice()
  .range([height - margin.bottom, margin.top])
xAxis = g => g
  .attr("transform", `translate(0,${height - margin.bottom})`)
  .call(d3.axisBottom(x).ticks(width / 80).tickSizeOuter(0));
yAxis = g => g
  .attr("transform", `translate(${margin.left},0)`)
  .call(d3.axisLeft(y))
  .call(g => g.select(".domain").remove())
  .call(g => g.select(".tick:last-of-type text").clone()
    .attr("x", 3)
    .attr("text-anchor", "start")
    .attr("font-weight", "bold")
    .text(data.y))
area = d3.area()
  .x(d => x(d.date))
  .y0(y(0))
  .y1(d => y(d.value))
const svg = d3.select('svg')
  .attr('width', width)
  .attr('height', height)

svg.append("path")
  .datum(data)
  .attr("fill", "steelblue")
  .attr("d", area);

svg.append("g")
  .call(xAxis);

svg.append("g")
  .call(yAxis);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg></svg>
```